# SVG moves out of position when screen size changes or doesn't scale

Tags: svg, responsive-design, resize, image-resizing, responsive

I've created an SVG and put the width as a percentage because I want it to resize to fit different screen widths, but when I resize the screen, the svg moves up and down and doesn't move left/right to stay in the centre. If I use pixels instead of percentages, it doesn't resize with the screen.

Preview didn't work on here so [here's the codepen link](http://codepen.io/mrseanbaines/pen/BQxVOX)
.

> HTML

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" id="main">
    <circle class="graph line line-1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="25%" stroke-width="5%" stroke="#f1c40f" fill="none" />
    <circle class="graph line line-2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="20%" stroke-width="5%" stroke="#e67e22" fill="none" />
    <circle class="graph line line-3" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="15%" stroke-width="5%" stroke="#00c0df" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

> CSS

```
#main {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.graph {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.graph.line {
  transform-origin: center;
  stroke-dasharray: 160%;
  animation: graph 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes graph {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160%;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 90%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what viewBox is for. With a viewBox, you establish a local coordinate system, which scales with your image. In your svg you simply use your local coordinates, and the image scales to any size...

```css
#main {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;left:0px;
  right:0px;bottom:0px;
  background:pink
}

.graph {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.graph.line {
  transform-origin: center;
  stroke-dasharray: 160%;
  animation: graph 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes graph {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 160%;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="main">
    <circle class="graph line line-1" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" stroke-width="5" stroke="#f1c40f" fill="none" />
    <circle class="graph line line-2" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke-width="5" stroke="#e67e22" fill="none" />
    <circle class="graph line line-3" cx="50" cy="50" r="15" stroke-width="5" stroke="#00c0df" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Sweet! How do I change the size of the svg though? If I put a set width on it then it sticks out outside of the page if I shrink the screen or view on mobile.

Comment: You can use any means of css to change the size of the svg.